# Swagger not scanning ApiModel and ApiModelProperty annotations in entity classes that are in a different jar file

Tags: java, rest, entity, swagger

I have the following two entity classes.

The first class is `SampleApiEntity`:

```
package my.company.rest;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@ApiModel (
    value       = "SampleApiEntity",
    description = "This is a sample entity from the Api package."
)
@Entity
public class SampleApiEntity
        implements Serializable
{
    public SampleApiEntity () {}

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column (nullable = false)
    @ApiModelProperty (
        value    = "level",
        required = true
    )
    private Integer   level;

    @Column (length = 255)
    @ApiModelProperty (
        value    = "description"
    )
    private String    description;

    @Column (nullable = false)
    @ApiModelProperty (
        value    = "time",
        required = true
    )
    private Timestamp time;

    @Id
    @Column (
        unique   = true,
        nullable = false
    )
    @Type (type = "pg-uuid")
    @ApiModelProperty (
        value    = "id",
        readOnly = true,
        dataType = "uuid",
        example  = "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000"
    )
    private UUID      sampleApiEntityId;

    public String getDescription ()
    {
        return this.description;
    }

    public Integer getLevel ()
    {
        return this.level;
    }

    public UUID getSampleApiEntityId ()
    {
        return this.sampleApiEntityId;
    }

    public Timestamp getTime ()
    {
        return this.time;
    }

    public void setDescription (String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setLevel (Integer level)
    {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public void setSampleApiEntityId (UUID sampleApiEntityId)
    {
        this.sampleApiEntityId = sampleApiEntityId;
    }

    public void setTime (Timestamp time)
    {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

The second class is `SampleModelEntity`:

```
package my.company.model;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@ApiModel (
    value       = "SampleModelEntity",
    description = "This is a sample entity from the Model package."
)
@Entity
public class SampleModelEntity
        implements Serializable
{
    public SampleModelEntity () {}

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column (nullable = false)
    @ApiModelProperty (
        value    = "level",
        required = true
    )
    private Integer   level;

    @Column (length = 255)
    @ApiModelProperty (
        value    = "description"
    )
    private String    description;

    @Column (nullable = false)
    @ApiModelProperty (
        value    = "time",
        required = true
    )
    private Timestamp time;

    @Id
    @Column (
        unique   = true,
        nullable = false
    )
    @Type (type = "pg-uuid")
    @ApiModelProperty (
        value    = "id",
        readOnly = true,
        example  = "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000"
    )
    private UUID      sampleModelEntityId;

    public String getDescription ()
    {
        return this.description;
    }

    public Integer getLevel ()
    {
        return this.level;
    }

    public UUID getSampleModelEntityId ()
    {
        return this.sampleModelEntityId;
    }

    public Timestamp getTime ()
    {
        return this.time;
    }

    public void setDescription (String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setLevel (Integer level)
    {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public void setSampleModelEntityId (UUID sampleModelEntityId)
    {
        this.sampleModelEntityId = sampleModelEntityId;
    }

    public void setTime (Timestamp time)
    {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

The only difference between the two classes is that they are defined in separate JAR files. `SampleApiEntity` is packaged in the same JAR as the REST resource class. `SampleModelEntity` is packaged in a separate JAR with other entity classes. The `swagger.yaml` file that is generated contains both classes, but lacks information provided by the `ApiModel` and `ApiModelProperty` annotations for the `SampleModelEntity` class.

Here is what I am seeing in the generated `swagger.yaml` file:

```
SampleApiEntity:
  type: "object"
  required:
  - "level"
  - "time"
  properties:
    level:
      type: "integer"
      format: "int32"
      description: "level"
    description:
      type: "string"
      description: "description"
    time:
      type: "string"
      format: "date-time"
      description: "time"
    sampleApiEntityId:
      type: "string"
      format: "uuid"
      example: "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000"
      description: "id"
      readOnly: true
  description: "This is a sample entity from the Api package."
SampleModelEntity:
  type: "object"
  properties:
    level:
      type: "integer"
      format: "int32"
    description:
      type: "string"
    time:
      type: "string"
      format: "date-time"
    sampleModelEntityId:
      type: "string"
      format: "uuid"
```

Can someone help me understand why the `ApiModel` and `ApiModelProperty` annotations are not generating output in `swagger.yaml`?

Comment: I've been doing some research and I've narrowed down the issue. The problem does not appear to be caused simply by the fact that the `SampleModelEntity` class is packaged in a separate JAR from the REST resource classes.

In the pom.xml file for the REST resource package, the dependency JAR that contains `SampleModelEntity` is declared with the `provided` scope. The scope appears to be causing the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. It turned out to be a class loading issue. I had an `ear` library that I was using to deploy a `war` library. Both the `war` and the `ear` contained a copy of the swagger-annotations artifact. This resulted in loaded annotation classes being different from what was packaged in the `ear`.

I solved the problem by modifying my `pom.xml` file for the `war` library. I added the swagger-annotations as an explicit dependency, and set its scope as `provided`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

You can find more information here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2582

Answer (score 4):

A little hint if you have a multi module maven project and use the maven swagger plugin. The same problem can appear in this constelation.

```
|-Module1 ( Rest paths )
 |--> pom.xml
|-Module2 ( Models )
 |--> pom.xml
|--> pom.xml ( Parent pom )
```

**Add the plugin to the parent pom and start it from here.**

This prevents the class loading problem and the annotations will be recognized and processed in the right way by the swagger "scanner".