# Swagger: @ApiModel annotation is ignored

Tags: jax-rs, swagger

I have a class which is annotated by @ApiModel. It contains a property which is an interface and the also with @ApiModel annotated implementation is located in another jar.

Example:

```
@ApiModel(description = "Container Object")
public class ContainerObject {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "generic field")
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type")
    private CustomData customData;
}
```

Custom Data is an empty Pojo. Its implementation is as followed:

```
@ApiModel
public class CustomDataX extends CustomData {
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "this is my super attribute")
    private String myAttribute;
}
```

Now my Swagger Config is as followed:

```
@Startup
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
    public JaxRsActivator() {
        super();
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[] { "http" });
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
    
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("ag.company.x");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
}
```

}

Sadly CustomDataX is not shown in the generated Swagger json. I'm using swagger-jaxrs version 1.5.22.

Do you know how to resolve this issue?

---

Edit: I already added a provided dependency to swagger-annotations as described in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48936884/2432030). Didn't work.

---